# Need to split string with regex

Tags: c#, .net, regex, sharepoint, sharepoint-designer

i need to split a string in C# .net.

output i am getting : **i:0#.f|membership|sdp950452@abctechnologies.com** or **i:0#.f|membership|tss954652@abctechnologies.com**
I need to remove *i:0#.f|membership|* and *@abctechnologies.com* from the string. out put i need is **sdp950452** or **tss954652**

also one more string I am getting is **Pawar, Jaywardhan** and i need it to be *jaywardhan pawar*

thanks,
Jay

Comment: And what is your input ? and what have you tried ?

Comment: i am getting current logged in sharepoint user by *currentUser.get_loginName()* through clientcontext but i am not able to split the output string

Answer (score 0):

Here is code example how you can do first part with Regex and the second with Splits and Replaces:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        //First part
        string first = "i:0#.f|membership|sdp950452@abctechnologies.com";
        string second = "i:0#.f|membership|tss954652@abctechnologies.com";
        string pattern = @"\|[A-Za-z0-9]+\@";
        Regex reg = new Regex(pattern);
        Match m1 = reg.Match(first);
        Match m2 = reg.Match(second);
        string result1 = m1.Value.Replace("|",string.Empty).Replace("@",string.Empty);
        string result2 = m2.Value.Replace("|", string.Empty).Replace("@", string.Empty);
        Console.WriteLine(result1);
        Console.WriteLine(result2);

        //Second part
        string inputString = "Pawar, Jaywardhan";
        string a = inputString.ToLower(); 
        var b = a.Split(' ');
        var result3 = b[1] + " " + b[0].Replace(",",string.Empty); 
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Linq to reduce the code lines
Link to [dotnetfiddle code sample](https://dotnetfiddle.net/uuiKfG)

```
using System.Linq;
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        //Extract email
        string a = "i:0#.f|membership|sdp950452@abctechnologies.com";
        string s = a.Split('|').Where(splitted => splitted.Contains("@")).FirstOrDefault().Split('@').First();
        Console.WriteLine(s);       

        //Format Name
        string name = "Pawar, Jaywardhan";
        string formatted = String.Join(" ",name.Split(',').Reverse()).ToLower().TrimStart().TrimEnd();
        Console.WriteLine(formatted);
    }
}
```